# Will open testing overwrite the existing Android app on production?

Tags: android, google-play-console

We already have our app in production, available in 2 regions (A and B). We have developed an overhaul of this application, and we would like to make it available for open testing in a different region C.

If I release a new version for Open testing targeting region C, will it overwrite the existing production app on the Play Store in regions A and B, or will it be available only in region C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this please> it's mentioned here that you can
"If your app has an existing production release, you can launch an open testing release in a new country without expanding your production release to the new country."

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en-GB&sjid=10830853594869045576-EU